# How to Solve Cumulative Layout Shift Caused by Announcement Bar?

Tags: css, cls

My eCommerce site (Shopify) has an announcement bar that pushes the rest of the page content down, causing CLS issues.

I've been searching through forums and articles for a while but all of the advice about solving CLS is super generic ("Make sure not to have pop-ups!") with a lack of guides for actual implementation.

The height of the announcement bar is a fixed 46 px on all devices, so this theoretically should be easy to fix by somehow assigning room for it in the theme files, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: show us the HTML/CSS in a snippet besides what you already have tried please.

Comment: @MahmoodKiaheyrati the HTML/CSS of what? The announcement bar?

Comment: anything that you think might help figuring out the problem and understanding the relation of different elements on the page. may i have your sites url?

Comment: URL: https://illuminatelabs.org/

Comment: CSS relating to announcement bar: .announcement-bar {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: Should I make position "static" and set the height of 46 px?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick! add it at the end of your css stylings.

```
.announcement-bar{
  position: absolute !important;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: small;
}
.announcement-bar__message{
 padding:0 !important;
  
}
```

Comment: Hey Mahmood thanks for your response. This is where things get a little tricky, because my site is built with Shopify which is a CMS, so in the theme files I don't actually see that HTML.

Comment: Hey so unfortunately that didn't work. When I use those settings it just makes the announcement bar overlap the existing page, rather than leave fixed room for the announcement bar. See here: https://imgur.com/a/SBXiQ24

Comment: I did increase the font weight and the height of the bar to 46 px instead of 25 because those are the values I want for those categories and I don't want to change those. I want to find a way to solve this CLS issue without making font smaller

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the announcement bar? I had similar issue but it was the admin bar which only shows if you are logged in (I assume as admin) which was causing biggest CLS. When tested in a private browser, no issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."